# Training a spaCy NER model and losses keep increasing with iterations and batches

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

```
# Create a blank 'en' model
nlp = spacy.blank("en")

# Create a new entity recognizer and add it to the pipeline
ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
nlp.add_pipe(ner)
# Add a new label
ner.add_label('LABEL')

# Start the training
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
# Loop for 10 iterations
for itn in range(10):
# Shuffle the training data
    random.shuffle(spacy_train)
    losses = {}
    # Batch the examples and iterate over them
    for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(spacy_train, size=spacy.util.compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001)):
        texts = [text for text, entities in batch]
        annotations = [entities for text, entities in batch]
        print("epoch: {} Losses: {}".format(itn, str(losses)))
    # Update the model
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, drop=0.5, losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
```

I'm trying to train a spaCy NER model and followed the spaCy training guide. Over time the losses should go down, however with each epoch it keeps going up. I've tried tweaking the batch size and iterations to no avail.

Examples:

epoch: 0 Losses: {}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 37.49999785423279}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 72.21390223503113}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 93.70724439620972}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 124.94790315628052}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 164.6911883354187}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 182.06093049049377}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 200.32691740989685}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 210.71145126968622}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 222.89578241482377}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 233.59122055233456}

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 245.26212133839726} 

epoch: 0 Losses: {'ner': 258.0684297736734}

For the last batch of this epoch, losses are 11,000. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Any suggestions for reducing the loss??

Answer (score 0):

Prob a little late, but.

Try printing on the first loop not inside the minibatch one